# How to display the uploaded files (such as doc,img,etc...) in edit page using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Question is if any possible to display the uploaded file name in edit page

My Code is

```
<div class="help-block with-errors pull-right"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="bill">Upload Proof</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="file" name="Customer_file" id="Customer_file" src="<?php echo $data[0]->file_path; ?>" class="" />
        </div>
        <div class="help-block with-errors pull-right"></div>
      </div>
      <input type="text" value="" name="file_path" id="file_path" hidden/>
       </div>
```

My Output Page:[image]

Can i possible to display already selected file name in upload proof field?

Comment: By setting img tag src value to an image filename?

Comment: Ok but the uploaded file was doc what can i do?

Comment: You can display the file name with a link to the file, and when editing you can upload new file, delete old file and update on the DB the new file name/path\.

Comment: can you provide source code?

Comment: Try to do that yourself, if you don't succeed then update your question with your code and I'll help.

Comment: ok i will try.But i cant understand correctly please provide any examples.

Comment: This my another question i didn't find the answer that can anyone  help? the question link https://stackoverflow.com/q/50504333/9658774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while storing the file its self, store type of file that is being uploaded.
Like if its a image, store img, if its a file then store file.

while fetching them fetch data in two arrays. all images in one array, all files in another array.

then in your view page, you can add `<img></img>` tag for images and '`<a></a>`' for files.

Comment: Any Example for <a> tag?

Comment: <a  href="<your file url>" target="_blank"> <your file name> </a> @PrakashT

Comment: This my another question i didn't find the answer that can you help me? the question link https://stackoverflow.com/q/50504333/9658774